# What did Sam see?

Tags: supernatural

In 1.05 Bloody Mary, to quote the [Supernatural Wikia](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Jess)

> Sam appears to see Jess on the street, in a long white nightgown.

It goes on to say it's unclear as to what he sees, but I wondered if there is any way to find out: What does Sam see?

Comment: I would guess at "No, the writers wanted to keep it ambiguous", since this was apparently after Sam's first premonition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I think that the writers of Supernatural intended to do this to create scary feeling about presence of Jess and to prepare the viewers for later Sam's halucinations and other abilities of Azazel's special childrens.
This maybe help you: [Transcript](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=1.05_Bloody_Mary_%28transcript%29)

Comment: Are those transcripts fan or official?